# Is it true that the data sent through GET method are limited?

Tags: http, url, get, character

In the past, I learned that the amount of data that can be sent through the HTTP GET method is limited and this is due to the limitation of the number of the characters in the URL, because an URL can not contain more than 255 characters.

But recently I noticed an URL that contains 294 characters where the query part (the string after the `?`) contains 269 characters.

So, is there really a limit in the data sent through GET ? or am I outdated ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a limit, and you can increase it. This is because data sent through the get method is passed through the url of the browser.
However different browsers may have different limits, and HTTP servers will also have different limits.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: It found that the limit is at least 2048 characters, so maybe I am outdated, thanks anyway !